# Reset Calendar Events in FullCalendar Angular 7

Tags: fullcalendar, angular7

I am using FullCalendar for Angular. I have a Dropdown by the side of calendar which contains list of Employees. When selected option is changed in dropdown, I need to show all events of specified employee. On change event of dropdown, I am calling **ngOnInit()** method to refresh the data.

```
handleEmployeeChange(employee_id) {
    this.router.navigate([`route-plan/${employee_id}`]);
    this.ngOnInit();
  }
```

And this is how I am trying to reset calendarEvents in `ngOnInit` method.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.calendarEvents = this.calendarEvents.splice(0, this.calendarEvents.length);
    console.log(this.calendarEvents);
}

 calendarEvents: EventInput[] = [];
```

In console, everytime I select a new employee, calendar events get appended to the list data. Thanks in advance.